# copy_from_user twice - character device

Tags: kernel, linux-device-driver

I've implemented a character device and I'd like to ask If this is correct:

1. In a Userspace I've a struct with 2 pointers.
2. I `write` this struct into my device.
3. In my `write` function in char device I `copy_from_user` this structure into kmalloced space.
4. After this I'm in KS and got 2 pointers to US so I want to `copy_from_user` each. Am I allowed to do so right after first `copy_from_user` by using this copied addresses? They point to a data in US application which called `write` function not to the `write` function argument `char *buf`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like it should work.

I'd probably be inclined to put this sort of thing into an `ioctl` instead of `write`, depending on whether the operation is similar to what other devices do when written to.  But that's just style; it's functionally the same.